# FirebaseAnimatedList in flutter giving type cast error

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

i want to fetch all data from firebase for that i am using the **FirebaseAnimatedList** an in the return we return an **map users** value but this map is giving error,

The code is:

```
body: FirebaseAnimatedList(
  query: dbref,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
      Animation<double> animation, var index) {
    Map users = snapshot.value as Map;
    users['key'] = snapshot.key;
    return listItem(Users: users);
  },
),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roiwd.png)

**Error is :-**

> The following _CastError was thrown building:
> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVwFl.png)

I want an solution or some ideas to do this work with different ways or finding the solution for this issue.

Comment: Apparently `snapshot.value` is not a `Map` in `Map users = snapshot.value as Map;`. Please edit your question to show: 1) how you initialize `dbref`, and 2) what data exists in the database at that path (as text, no screenshot needed), You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).